# "AAPT: error: resource not found" when I'm testing

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I've written an instrumented test. When I run it I get an error:

> /Users/ilamasin/StudioProjects/ecwid/general/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/drawable/horizontal_divider_with_padding.xml:6:
>   AAPT: error: resource dimen/horizontal_divider_thickness (aka
>   com.ecwid.android.reports.test:dimen/horizontal_divider_thickness) not
>   found.

It's my drawable in project and it exists. My project runs and works. But test doesn't. Did anyone has this error? I use Junit and Mockito (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to dimen file and add value to this-:

```
res->values->dimen and give value to dimen/horizontal_divider_thickness
```

or go to drawable file and pass value i.e `15dp` or `20dp` whatever you want to add.

Comment: It works in my case. This dimen was in other module. With build it worked well but in test it didn't work.